# Как заменить на динамический массив

Tags: c++, массивы, ассемблер, память, матрицы

задание состояло в том, чтобы заменить первую строку на первый столбец в матрице, если их суммы равно, данное задание нужно было сделать используя С++ и Ассемблер. Сделала данное задание, но преподаватель сказал исправить, чтобы размер массива вводился с клавиатуры и потом динамически выделялась память, а как это исправить не знаю. Спасибо всем кто откликнется.

Код с++:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

extern "C" void asm_proc(int *a, int); // описание прототипа ASM-подпрограммы

using namespace std;

void Input(int arr[3][3]);
void Output(int arr[3][3]);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    int a[3][3] = { 0 };

    cout << "Задание: Если сумма элементов первой строки = сумме элементов первого столбца, " << endl << "обмнять элементы первой строки с элементами первого столбца " << endl << endl;
    cout << "Исходный массив: " << endl;
    Input(a);
    Output(a);

    asm_proc(&a[0][0], 3);
    cout << "Массив после оброботки: " << endl;
    Output(a);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void Input(int arr[3][3])//функция заполнения массива с входными параметрами: массив и ограничение
{
    srand(time(NULL)); // "инициализация" генератора случайных чисел
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
}
void Output(int arr[3][3])//функция вывода массива в консоль
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << setw( 5)  << arr[i][j];
        cout << endl;//переход на следующую строку
    }
}
```

Код асм:

```
.386
.model flat, c

public  asm_proc

.data
    summ    dd  0
.code
asm_proc    proc
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp


    mov     esi, [ebp + 8]
    mov     ecx, [ebp + 12] 
@add_summ:
    lodsd
    add     [summ], eax
loop @add_summ

    mov     esi, [ebp + 8]
    mov     ecx, [ebp + 12]
    mov     ebx, ecx
    shl     ebx, 2
@sub_summ:
    mov     eax, [esi]
    sub     [summ], eax
    add     esi, ebx
loop @sub_summ

; проверка равенства строк через разность суммы

  cmp     summ, 0
  jne     @exit


    mov     esi, [ebp + 8]
    mov     edi, [ebp + 8]
    mov     ecx, [ebp + 12]
;делаем обмен
@swap:
    push    [edi]
    push    [esi]
    pop     [edi]
    pop     [esi]
    add     esi, 4
    add     edi, ebx
loop @swap

@exit:
    leave
    retn
asm_proc    endp
end
```

Вот, что получилось после исправления,но теперь задание не выполнятся, как нужно исправить код из ассемблера?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

extern "C" void asm_proc(int** a, int); // описание прототипа ASM-подпрограммы

using namespace std;

void Input(int **arr, const int n, const int m);
void Output(int** arr, const int n, const int m);
int main()
{    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    cout << "Задание: Если сумма элементов первой строки = сумме элементов первого столбца, " << endl << "обмнять элементы первой строки с элементами первого столбца " << endl << endl;
    /*ЗАДАЁМ ЧИСЛО ЯЧЕЕК ВО ВРЕМЯ РАБОТЫ ПРОГРАММЫ*/
    int n;
    cout << "Введите размерность квадратной матрицы: ";
    cin >> n;
    /*ДАЁМ ПРОГРАММЕ ПАМЯТЬ*/
    int** a = new int* [n];//Создание строк
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = new int[n];//Создание колонок для каждой строки

    cout << "Введите исходный массив: " << endl;
    Input(a,n,n);
    cout << "Исходный массив: " << endl;
    Output(a,n,n);
    asm_proc(a, n);
    cout << "Массив после оброботки: " << endl;
    Output(a,n,n);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void Input(int** arr, const int n, const int m)//функция заполнения массива с входными параметрами: массив и ограничение
{
    srand(time(NULL)); // "инициализация" генератора случайных чисел
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cin >> arr[i][j];
    }
}
void Output(int** arr, const int n, const int m)//функция вывода массива в консоль
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << setw(5) << arr[i][j];
        cout << endl;//переход на следующую строку
    }
}
```

Comment: Сударушка, Вам нужно погуглить динамические массивы C++, а также указатели. Разница между статическим и динамическим массивом в том, что размер первого должен быть известен заранее и память выделяется под весь массив сразу одним большим куском. Динамический массив нужен тогда, когда размер массива заранее неизвестен или может изменяться.

Comment: Я знаю как работать с динамическим массивом на с++, но как его передавать в ассемблерную процедуру и как там с ним работать нет

Comment: Оу, ну тут нужно гуглить уже в сторону выделения памяти на языке ассемблера. Ужас у Вас, а не задание, если честно!

Comment: Ага, так в том дело, что задание было сделать с обычным массивом, но когда я ей это показала, она решила, что нужно всё переделывать под динамический(

Comment: Понимаю, сударушка, такое нередко бывает

Answer (score 1):

Заменяем ваше

```
int a[3][3] = { 0 };
```

на что-то типа

```
int **a = new int*[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    a[i] = new int[n];
```

и работаем с `a` почти так же, как с двумерным массивом - передавая его в функции как `int**a`, и обращаясь к элементам, как и ранее - `a[i][j]`.

Comment: Исправила, но перестала работать процедура, которую вызываю с ассемблера

Comment: Ну так теперь же это совсем другое представление в памяти... С++ не позволяет сделать динамический двумерный массив, указав размеры во время работы - только при компиляции. Так что приходится использовать обходные пути. Я предложил один. Второй - взять одномерный массив, и обращаться, каждый раз самостоятельно вычисляя из номера столбца и строки индекс в одномерном массиве. Что сложнее, и все равно требует переписывать код.